# I parsed nested json data with gson but return null

Tags: java, android, null, gson

I'm a new android developer.. So I have a problem this.. I'm parsing nested json data with gson but return null varaible. Please help me.!
My json Data is:

```
{"result":"success","data":{"Items":[{"id":"5b7c8950-692a-11e6-a3c9-03b4285ed321","accountName":"5b7c8950-692a-11e6-a3c9-03b4285ed321@finanskutusu.com","userId":"111903139847063022019"}],"Count":1,"ScannedCount":12}}
```

AccountModel.java :

```
public class AccountModel {

private String result;

public Data data;

public String getResult() {
    return result;
}
public void setResult(String result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}}
```

Data.java :

```
public class Data {

public Items[] Items;
private String Count;
private String ScannedCount;

public Items[] getItems() {
    return Items;
}

public void setItems(Items[] Items) {
    this.Items = Items;
}

public String getCount() {
    return Count;
}

public void setCount(String Count) {
    this.Count = Count;
}

public String getScannedCount() {
    return ScannedCount;
}

public void setScannedCount(String ScannedCount) {
    this.ScannedCount = ScannedCount;
}}
```

Items.java :

```
public class Items {
private String id;
private String accountName;
private String userId;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAccountName() {
    return accountName;
}

public void setAccountName(String accountName) {
    this.accountName = accountName;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}}
```

Thanks..

Comment: What is null ? data ? How are you invoking Gson ?

Comment: I think you should use  `List<Items>` instead of `Items[]`

Comment: @RobertEstivill  
Null varabile is data = null result = null

Comment: if result is null then you have a problem parsing the root json object. How are you calling Gson ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have parsed the data successfully using the model classes provided (no changes). Here is the parser program,

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create(); 
    AccountModel am = gson.fromJson("{\"result\":\"success\",\"data\":    {\"Items\":[{\"id\":\"5b7c8950-692a-11e6-a3c9- 03b4285ed321\",\"accountName\":\"5b7c8950-692a-11e6-a3c9-03b4285ed321@finanskutusu.com\",\"userId\":\"111903139847063022019\"}],\"Count\":1,\"ScannedCount\":12}}", AccountModel.class);
    System.out.println(am.getResult());
    System.out.println(am.getData().getCount());
    Items i[] = am.getData().getItems();
    System.out.println(i[0].getAccountName());
```

Output

```
success
1
5b7c8950-692a-11e6-a3c9-03b4285ed321@finanskutusu.com
```